# Using Enable Attachments tool in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, photos, attachments, arcgis-collector

I am working through the tutorial for ArcGIS Collector - Step 8, which says :  To allow users to take pictures in the field and attach them to their assessment reports, enable attachments on the feature class you just created. To do so, right-click the feature class in the Catalog window, select Manage, and click Create Attachments.

This is supposed to be available under the Data Management Tools - but all I see is a Photo tool, which does not appear to work the same way.

Step 1 - need to "Enable Attachments" - but can't find the right tool
Step 2 - right click feature class in catalog window....
Other users posted that you cannot add attachments to geodatabases with Desktop version, then why is this an instruction under this tutorial, which is for Desktop version?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.1.

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m90000000r000000

Comment: Can you edit your Question to include the license level of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using, please?  You need Standard or Advanced in order to be able to enable attachments.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble because I was on a Basic (ArcView) licence level. When I changed my licence level to Advanced I was able to right click on the geodatabase and see the enable attachments option.